# How to add extensionless files (i.e. makefiles) in source insight?

Tags: source-insight

**How to add extensionless files (i.e. makefiles) in source insight?**

Working in Source Insight 3.X. An existing c/cpp project code is loaded. When I search in project window, make/makefile which are extension less are not showing. How can I confirm that all the extension less files are also synced and shown in project window when searching with names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by allowing unknown file types to add in the project from,

> Menu -> Project -> Add or Remove Project Files -> uncheck "Show only known document types"

[image]